# Schengen Visa Free Travel as Tourist (90/180) Immediately Following Long Stay (D Type Visa)

Tags: visas, schengen, europe

I have been residing in France for a year on a D type visa.
Now, by the end of this year the visa will be over, and I would like to take advantage of being a Schengen visa free passport holder (annex II country, like Argentina, Australia or Singapore for example) to spend another 3 months as a tourist in Europe, immediately following my current stay.

1. Do you think I should exit upon visa's expiry and re-enter the Schengen again, or can I just stay for the extra 3 months without leaving?
2. In case I do exit end re-enter, I thought of doing that through the border in Andorra (it's not Schengen, but not sure if they stamp the passport), or make my way south to cross the border to Gibraltar (also not Schengen - and they do stamp for sure).

What would you advise on the situation?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit complicated, but, if you stayed in France for the last 6 months without leaving the country, you can spend an additional period of 3 months in any *other* EU country/-ies after expiration date of your D type visa.

In case you stayed elsewere in EU during the last 6 months of your D type visa, that time will be substracted from those 3 months you can stay *after* the expiration of the D type visa.

More information can be found at [EU Migration and home affairs](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/index_en.htm) website.

Not sure about re-entry, though. Shouldn't be a problem, considering you don't need a visa for 3 months.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: Thank you. Are you saying that in practice, in the scenario you have mentioned I do not actually need to re-enter, and can just continue to stay the extra 3 months?

Comment: @derekbvb Yes. Glad I could help.